# Setup dll doesn't run in WindowsCE when attached to CAB

Tags: windows-ce, installation, cab

I have used the steps outlined here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx

to create and attached a setup.dll to my previously created CAB.

But the setup.dll doesn't run.

Any ideas?

I am using .net CF 2.0 and my OS is Windows CE.

Comment: You say you attached a setup.dll to your "previously created CAB".  How do you mean exactly?  You would need to completely recreate the CAB to include a setup.dll.

Comment: I used the steps indicated in the article above. You do not need to re-create the CAB. If you do, the article is not indicating that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted to making the staff that installs the app, click on setup.exe manually after the CAB unpacks the files.
The reason being is that there is no specific SDK for Win CE 6.0. I have struggled with this issue for 2 days now without any solution in sight.

Hopes this saves someone time and effort.